# HTTP Status 404 - Not Found Java Web

Tags: java, web

Actualmente me encuentro trabajando en Java Web, en un CRUD implementando el MVC. En el código no veo ningún problema, y a la hora de ejecutarlo me aparece el siguiente error:

> HTTP Status 404 - Not Found

> type: Status report

> message: Not Found

> description: The requested resource is not available.

> GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.1.1

Realmente no se a que se deba.
Agradecería muchísimo su ayuda.

Comment: Recomiendo encarecidamente leas [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), para saber cómo formular una buena pregunta. La respuesta 404 - Not Found, significa EXACTAMENTE eso: No se encontró el recurso. Estudia un poco acerca de los [Códigos de respuesta HTTP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status)

Comment: Gracias. Quizás no fui muy clara a  la hora de formular la pregunta. Según lo que leí, es que el navegador no reconoce la URL, pero quisiera saber a que se debe esto. Yo estoy trabajando con Netbeans y Xampp.

Comment: Para poder responder esta pregunta, deberás darnos más información. Necesitamos ver la estructura de tus controladores, la estructura de tus rutas, entre otras cosas. Construye un [ejemplo mínimo completo y verificable para que podamos ayudarte más](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Sin un ejemplo para probar difícilmente darte una solución, aparte que no especificas la tecnología que utilizas, porque puede ser patrón MVC pero hay multitud de frameworks y librerías  en java que se basan en este patrón.